# VB.net Linq Join Expression Error

Tags: vb.net

```
    Public Class ListComparison
    Public Function CompareTwoLists(Of T1, T2, TDuplicate As DuplicateExpression)(list1 As IEnumerable(Of T1), list2 As IEnumerable(Of T2), compareValue As Func(Of T1, T2, Boolean), DuplicateExpression As List(Of TDuplicate)) As Boolean
        Return list1.[Select](Function(item1) list2.Any(Function(item2) compareValue(item1, item2))).All(Function(search) search) AndAlso list2.[Select](Function(item2) list1.Any(Function(item1) compareValue(item1, item2))).All(Function(search) search)
    End Function
    Public Function CompareLists(Of T1, TDuplicate As DuplicateExpression)(list1 As IEnumerable(Of T1), list2 As IEnumerable(Of T1), DuplicateExpression As List(Of TDuplicate)) As String
        Dim InvalidDuplicateExpression As List(Of TDuplicate) = New ExtensionHelper().ValidateColumnInList(Of T1, TDuplicate)(DuplicateExpression)
        Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        If InvalidDuplicateExpression.Count() <= 0 Then
            Dim Fields As String() = DuplicateExpression.[Select](Function(x) x.ExpressionName).ToArray()
            Dim JoinExp = list1.Join(list2, Fields)
            Dim IsDuplicate As Boolean = True
            IsDuplicate = CompareTwoLists(list1, list2, Function(listx1, listx2) JoinExp.Any(), DuplicateExpression)
            If IsDuplicate Then
                Return js.Serialize(New With { _
                    Key .IsValidateExpression = True, _
                    Key .IsValidateDuplicate = IsDuplicate, _
                    Key .Message = "Duplicate Items in the List" _
                })
            Else
                Return js.Serialize(New With { _
                    Key .IsValidateExpression = True, _
                    Key .IsValidateDuplicate = IsDuplicate _
                })
            End If
        Else
            Return js.Serialize(New With { _
                Key .IsValidateExpression = False, _
                Key .InvalidExpressions = InvalidDuplicateExpression, _
                Key .Message = "Duplicate Expression is not Invalid" _
            })
        End If
    End Function        
    Public Shared Function CreateSelector(Of T)(PropertyNames As IEnumerable(Of String)) As Func(Of T, Object)
        Dim SourceType = GetType(T)
        Dim Parameter = Expression.Parameter(SourceType, "e")
        Dim Properties = PropertyNames.[Select](Function(Name) Expression.PropertyOrField(Parameter, Name)).ToArray()
        Dim Selector = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Object))(Expression.[Call](GetType(Tuple), "Create", Properties.[Select](Function(p) p.Type).ToArray(), Properties), Parameter)
        Return Selector.Compile()
    End Function
    Public Shared Function Join(Of T)(Left As IEnumerable(Of T), Right As IEnumerable(Of T), PropertyNames As IEnumerable(Of String)) As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of T, T))
        Dim KeySelector = CreateSelector(Of T)(PropertyNames)
        Return Left.Join(Right, KeySelector, KeySelector, AddressOf Tuple.Create)
    End Function
End Class
```

When I compile this code I am getting following Error.

> Error 15  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Join' accepts this number of arguments.

```
Dim JoinExp = list1.Join(list2, Fields)
```

The error is on above line. This is mainly using for List comparison with Dynamic column properties. This code is properly working in C#.net. When I convert C#.net code to Vb.net; getting this error. How to solve this in Vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the C# `Join` function was an extension method

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Join<T> (
    this IEnumerable<T> Left,
    IEnumerable<T> Right,
    IEnumerable<string> PropertyNames
)
```

In which case you must [add the `<Extension>` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936(v=vs.110).aspx) to it in VB.NET.